# Passing JSON array in AJAX call sending null in MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to pass an array of json objects to my controller action and it keeps coming in as null.

**Javascript Code**

```
function UpdateSelected() {
    var items = {};

    //Loop through grid / sub grids and create json array
    $('.k-detail-row .k-grid').each(function () {
        var grid = $(this).data("kendoGrid");
        var selectedElements = grid.select();
        for (var j = 0; j < selectedElements.length; j++) {
            var item = grid.dataItem(selectedElements[j]);
            var json = item.toJSON();
            items = [].concat(items, json);
        }
    })

    //shift the first empty space out
    items.shift();

    //items is ready to send
    alert(JSON.stringify(items));
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: '/Update/GetSchematicsForSelectedVariants',
        type: 'GET',
        data: JSON.stringify(items),
        success: function (data) {
            alert("success");
        }
    });
}
```

**The Json array looks like this:**

[image]

**Controller Action**

```
public JsonResult GetSchematicsForSelectedVariants(List<VariantViewModel> vm)//vm coming in null
{
    return Json(_dataAccessService.GetSchematicsForMacroVariants(vm),JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**VariantViewModel**

```
public class VariantViewModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Variant { get; set; }
}
```

So I am not to sure what is going wrong here. My list is being passed in as null. I am not to keen on passing json objects to the controller but I believe I have the gist of what I need.

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: I could be wrong about this, but I think your problem could be that you are passing an array into `data`, rather than key - values.

Comment: change `type:'get'` to `type:'post'` or add `[HttpGet]` to the controller method.

Comment: You need to pass this type of data as a `POST` request. When it is a `GET` the data gets appended to the url. If you want to keep it as a `GET`, try doing `processData: false`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions but neither of those worked. I changed the method to a POST and also tried changing the controller to HttpGet.

Comment: Try this @Selthien, tag your method in c# with `[HttpPost]` change your ajax type to `POST`, and dont stringify your data.

Comment: Tried that and it still did not work. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: I figured out the problem I posted the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the issue. My data needed to be passed in the following way in my AJAX request. Can't believe I missed this honestly.

```
$.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: '/Update/GetSchematicsForSelectedVariants',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'ListOfVariants' : items},
        success: function (data) {
            alert("success");
        }
    });
```

Thank you everyone for your comments it helped point me in the right direction.